# Selinux reference one type in another file

Tags: android-source, selinux

I'm working on a avc denial in AOSP project.

When I try to fix it in the appropriate file: vendor/somevendor/common/sepolicy/product/private/some_app.te

```
allow some_app some_debugfs:dir search;
```

I get that some_debugfs is not defined.

I found it declared in: device/somedevice/common/sepolicy/file.te:

```
type some_debugfs, fs_type, sysfs_type, debugfs_type;
```

But if I declare it in vendor/somevendor/common/sepolicy/product/private/file.te I get a duplicate error.

I am at loss at what to do. If I declare it I get a duplicate error, if I don't declare it I get an undefined error.